# Разница в терминах Core и Kernel.

Tags: терминология

В чём разница между этими двумя терминами, когда речь идёт о "ядре"?

Какие из этих двух можно применять для обозначения ядра ОС/языка/граф. движка/программы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исторически сложилось, что о ядре ОС говорят kernel, а о ядре разных приложений и систем (даже распределённых) говорят CORE.

Comment: Да, но вот в рубях есть объект в который понапихано стандартных функций и он называется Kernel. Смысл двух терминов совершенно одинаков?

Comment: Да нету большой разницы, мне кажется.
Можно заглянуть на вики-словарь http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kernel
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/core

Оба слова могут описывать почти одинаковые сущности, но в то же время я бы сказал, что CORE это более общее понятие.

Comment: Если честно, я вообще не видел употребления слова core именно к программным продуктам. Разве что в "core dump", но это устойчивое выражение. А kernel - преимущественно видел употребляемым к ядрам операционных систем. Хотя

Comment: Я много раз видел слово CORE именно в программных продуктах

Answer (score -3):

kernel это микроядро, а core это прочие служебные сервисы/модули/примитивы/функции/компоненты. например, из описания одной микроядерной os:

**kernel**: executive and memory manager

**core**: time and calendar, device manager, heap, drivers and board setup, flash manager, file system server and the program manager